# How can I make parameters optional?

Tags: pentaho, report-designer

I need some help with pentaho report designer.

I've used some parameters to filter my data, but, it seems that I'm obliged to filter on these parameters to show data on my charts.

So, this is what I want, I need to make my parameters optional. It means that I want to show global views even if I don't select a parameter.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Untick the mandatory checkbox in the parameter settings dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a hidden parameter; Let's call it "Flag" that tests whether the parameter are set, by using this post-processing formula.

```
=OR(ISNA([date_from]); ISNA([date_to]))
```

and then in your query  reference that new parameter:

```
Select .....
where ${Flag} = TRUE OR (date between ${date_from} and ${date_to})
```